# Weird use of Glasser's Master Theorem

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the following enumeration of the rational numbers in $[\,0,1)$:
$$0, \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{5}{6}, \cdots$$

Where the list is first group sorted by ascending denominator, then each group in ascending numerator, and deleting all reducible elements. Obviously $0$ is an exception to this sorting.

This is an arbitrary choice, but the simplest to read (in my opinion)

Also, the list begins at $0$ i.e. $r_0 = 0, r_1 = \frac{1}{2}, \cdots$

Define the following sequence of functions $\phi_n(x)$

$$\phi_0(x) = x- \pi \cot{\pi x}, \phi_1(x) = x - \pi \left(\cot{\pi x} + \cot{\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} \right) \\\\ \phi_2(x) = x - \pi \left(\cot{\pi x} + \cot{\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} + \cot{\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)}\right) \\\\ \phi_3(x) = x - \pi \left(\cot{\pi x} + \cot{\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} + \cot{\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)} + \cot{\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)}\right) \\\\ \phi_n(x) = x - \pi \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \cot{\pi \left(x-r_k\right)}\right)$$
where $r_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ element in the enumeration described above.

Assuming $\displaystyle A = \text{PV} \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, \text{d}x \right)$ is finite and is Lesbegue measurable,

consider the following sequence of integrals

$$I_n = \text{PV} \left( \int_{\infty}^\infty f(\phi_n(x)) \, \text{d}x \right)$$

It can be shown with Glasser's Master Theorem, that for any finite $n$, $I_n = A$

What happens in the limit, for $n \to \infty$ ?

Is the limit of $I_n$ still equal to $A$?

If so, how can I rigorously prove it?

***Edit:***

The motivation of this question was out of simple curiosity.

I wanted to see what would happen to the integral if I densely filled the function's argument with singularities, and whether any infinite weirdness happens, as is often the case.

An internet person argued that if one chooses to accept the Axiom of Countable Choice, then the limit exists and is equal to $A$.

Is this the case?

Comment: I assume your question is based on the fact that $\cot(\pi z)$ can be expanded into sum of fractions $\frac{1}{z^2-n^2}$. Following the notation on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem, I think your question is: does Glasser’s Master theorem still true when $N\to \infty$? This is same as asking: is$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \int f(\sum^N)=  \int f(\sum^\infty)$$true? This should be closely related to the Dominated Convergence Theorem. Do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: It seems to convey what I am asking.

Comment: However, I’m not sure if $I_n=A$ is true even if $n$ is finite, since the GMT may be not applicable(because an infinite sum is involved). If you can show $I_n=A$ for finite $n$, I’m quite sure $I_\infty=A$ as well. Can you show $I_n=A$?

Comment: For any particular value of $n$, the resultant $\phi_n (x)$ can be decomposed into a sum of $n$ countably infinite sum of poles. A union of a finite number of countably infinite sets is still countably infinite, as you can just biject them onto $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$, provided you take care with overlapping elements, but in this case, there aren't any..

Comment: @Szeto See the version of Glasser's Master Theorem described here: http://sos440.blogspot.com/2017/01/glassers-master-theorem.html
Also, in his original proof, Glasser wrote down the case taken to infinity, and the cotangent result as a direct consequence.

Comment: I can’t find his proof. But, if his theorem is true even for infinite sums in a general sense, then since $\phi _\infty (x) $ is still $x$ minus an infinite sum of fractions $\frac{1}{x-a}$, GMT is applicable and thus $I_\infty=A$.